# Does the struct get freed this way in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free

I have the following struct which I use to implement a priority queue

```
struct q_element
{
    //Declaration of struct members
    int element;
    int priority;
    struct q_element *next_element;
};
```

and I use a pointer to a struct 'cur' to start from the first item in the queue

```
struct q_element* cur = start_element;
```

and keep moving until I find the one I want to delete from list.

```
while (cur->priority!=max_priority)
    cur = cur->next_element;
```

Does the following line of code actually free the struct? Because 'cur' is a pointer to the struct I wasn't completely sure.

```
free(cur);
```

Comment: If you `malloc`'d `cur`, then yes, `free(cur)` frees it. If you didn't, then calling `free` on it is an error.

Comment: Yes because you could have `struct q_element x; struct q_element *ptr = &x;` and so on, which would be very unusual but possible, so you must explain how do you generate the list, and `free(cur)` will only free that pointer, the `next_element`s need their own `free()`.

Comment: yes i did use malloc.. so i'm not freeing the pointer or anything else this way? free actually frees the struct pointed by the pointer I gave it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to `free`, so `free(cur)` is the way to go, assuming that the `struct` itself has been allocated using `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`. Specifically, if you allocated your `curr` in the automatic memory (i.e. on the stack) you are not supposed to call `free` on it.

It looks like `q_element` is part of a linked list. Freeing the `struct` itself will not free other `struct`s pointed to by it, so if you'd like to `free` the `struct` along with its tail, you need to write a loop.

Finally, when you `free` memory pointed to by some pointer in your program, it is a very good idea to assign `NULL` to the pointer that you `free`d to avoid accidental double-freeing and undefined behavior on accessing freed memory.

Comment: @Yiannis In your example `cur` is a pointer to struct. The pointer is not what's being deallocated, it's what the pointer points to. If the struct the `cur` is pointing to has been allocated with `calloc`, then the call of `free` is valid.